# Cisco 2960 switch will not recognize new TACACS+ commands

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, tacacs

I'm trying to add tacacs info to a switch.  However, I'm unable to use the new tacacs commands, even though the switch tells me to.

**WS-C2960-24PC-L - Version 15.0(2)SE5**

```
switch(config)#tacacs-server host 10.1.1.1
Warning: The cli will be deprecated soon
'tacacs-server host 10.1.1.1'
Please move to 'tacacs server <name>' CLI
```

Ok, so I'll use it that way...

```
wtc2b1asw01(config)#tacacs server ABC
                          ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Guess I can't.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sw-R2-3#show ver | i Software
Cisco IOS Software, C2960S Software (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
sw-R2-3#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
sw-R2-3(config)#tacacs?
tacacs  tacacs-server  

sw-R2-3(config)#tacacs ?
  server  Server configuration

sw-R2-3(config)#tacacs server ?
  WORD  Name for the tacacs server configuration

sw-R2-3(config)#tacacs server foo 
sw-R2-3(config-server-tacacs)#
```

`aaa new-model` maybe?

[back story]
This is one of many of my Cisco peavs... When I was first starting out with IOS (back when IOS 10 was new), I sat down with the ~1000 page documentation on authentication configuration. After a day of "*why the f*** doesn't any of this work*", I got to page 958-ish, where, as a *complete* after thought, the authors finally mention, "*and you have to enter* aaa new-model *to turn any of this on.*" I think I actually burned that handbook. (and was never allowed to go to NANOG, because I might "do something" to that author.) F'ing CCIEs!

Comment: wow, I knew it was something simple. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As with all things learned, there's a story there.